# how to catch org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

i am trying to use hibernate in spring to do sql Queries i am able to succeed in executing queries but i am getting some errors if user gives same user id which has primary key constraint or else giving string in the parameter for int so i want to catch these exceptions and send user custom exceptions like primary key constraint exception,NullValue Exception etc. like that

error for primary key constraint i am getting is :

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

so is there any way to catch exceptions depending on error so that on that specific exception i can send user my custom error message . Right now i am sending user the catched exception error but user dont get what the error is so i want to send custom errors

so is there any way to catch exceptions depending on specific error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the Spring [ExceptionTranslator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLExceptionTranslator.html), as it allows you to transform SQLExceptions into DataAccessExceptions, including your own custom versions, which would allow you to produce exceptions with your desired message for the user. In your case, you could extend the [HibernateExceptionTranslator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateExceptionTranslator.html), to get more specific exceptions than the one the default Hibernate implementation delivers to you.

Comment: Thanks ,can you provide solution for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411475/how-to-implement-below-c-sharp-code-in-java

Comment: Not really my field of experience, sorry, but I added a link found via Google.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you got is already translated by Spring ExceptionTranslator, the original exception is a dependent Integrity or Constraint violation exception, that has been encapsulated into a generic Spring Exception.

Maybe you could build a custom bean with a `HashMap` where spring translated exception is mapped to a message of your own. For example:

```
...
Map<Class<String, String> exMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
exMap.put("org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException", "Clarifying message to user ...");
...
try{
   ...
}catch(Exception ex){
    String message = exMap.get(ex.getclass().getName());
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps.